# Create callback executing foobar twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My model looks like this:

```
  after_create :foobar
  after_update :foobar

  def foobar
    update_attributes(:foo => 'bar')
  end
```

Whenever I create an object. It calls foobar (`after_create` callback). But it also automatically triggers the `after_update` callback.

Basically, when I create an object its calling foobar twice.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why even use `update_attributes` for this? What's stopping you from using a setter?

Comment: a setter as in `foo = 'bar'; save`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `after_create` you're calling `update_attributes()` which triggers the `after_update` callback.

Basically you're calling it twice. You need to figure out what the proper flow is for your program, and make it such that `foobar` only gets called once. Right now, the code you've written is executing as designed.

One suggestion would be using `before_[action]` attributes instead to modify the fields in the incoming object. That way the object only gets saved once. The way you've written it, new objects get saved twice - once when they're created, and once when they're updated via `update_attributes`.

I see that this is example code, but I'm not sure how, in `after_update`, since you explicitly make ANOTHER update, how this isn't getting wrapped up in an infinite loop. Might be able to give a better answer if you post actual code.